# Mathjs 'The global config is read-only'?

Tags: javascript, angular, mathjs

I am using Angular 8 and math.js library for big number manipulation.

I just have an updated version of math.js from 5.4.0 to 6.2.3.

I am using math.js in my component in this way:

```
import * as mathjs from 'mathjs';

constructor() {
   mathjs.config({ number: 'BigNumber', precision: 128 });
}
```

Suddenly new error appears after the update.

> Error: The global config is readonly.  Please create a mathjs
> instance if you want to change the default configuration.  Example:
>
> import { create, all } from 'mathjs';
> const mathjs = create(all);
>
> mathjs.config({ number: 'BigNumber' });

I tried `import { create, all } from 'mathjs`, but those methods do not exist at all.

What is the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally found solution.

First I needed to remove line:

```
import * as mathjs from 'mathjs';
```

This line does not make seance anymore since we need to create variable with this name which will be new instance of mathjs with new configuration.

```
import { create, all, MathJsStatic } from 'mathjs';

private mathjs: Partial<MathJsStatic>;

  constructor() {
    this.mathjs = create(all, { number: 'BigNumber', precision: 128 });
  }
```

If we need the same configuration of mathjs over all the application, the good way is to create a service and use the same instance everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if solve your problem, But as per the error you should create a new instance and use later like below -

```
import { create, all } from 'mathjs';
  const mathjs = new create(all);
  mathjs.config({ number: 'BigNumber' });
```

Comment: Yeas, I tried this but since I did not updated @types/mathjs I got errors. 
Now I have 2 problems with line const mathjs = new create(all);
    1) Shadowed name: 'mathjs' (no-shadowed-variable)
    2) (property) create: (factories: FactoryFunctionMap, config: ConfigOptions) => Partial<MathJsStatic>
import create
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)